# WP8 webbrowser control saving an image

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

In internet explorer, I can save the image by holding on it and click to save image. But there is not such a option in my webbrowser. Any idea about how to activate it ? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this directly. You have to [parse the html document](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HTML_Page_parsing_using_HTMLAgilityPack) for all the images in the document and show a different menu to select and donwload them. Downlaod the selected with with HttpWebRequest

```
HttpWebRequest WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
WebRequest.BeginGetResponse((asyncCallback) =>
{
    try
    {            
        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        library.SavePicture(imageName, WebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncCallback).GetResponseStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}, WebRequest);
```

Comment: how do I get the current url ?

Comment: Url for the current page in the `webBrowserControl`? or the Image Url?

Comment: You can get the current page Url with `webBrowserControl1.Source.AbsoluteUri`